# included module methods cant be called in class methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, include

I have a module `RegexHelper` which contain methoids to verify if a string is only numeric:

```
module RegexHelper
  def is_numeric?(str)
    !!str.match(/^[0-9]+$/)
  end
end
```

And I include this module in several classes and it works well when I try using them in instance methods. But now I want to use them in class methods and it simply doesnt work eaven calling`RegexHelper.is_numeric?(my_str)` doesnt work for me.

I think the problem might be that the `include RegeHelper` is exexute when creating a new object. So how can I make this work for the whole class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
extend RegeHelper
```

`include` is for adding instance methods to a class and `extend` is for adding class methods.